# wordpress plugin with external links

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to create a wp plugin but wordpress.org will not publish it for me as long as it contains external links. I have the plugin pulling some info from my website's db and there isn't other way to do it. As far as I know. I was wondering if there is a way to do it somehow?
i.e the plugin pulls links from my db and displays them on the plugin user's site.

Comment: I dont think they won't publish them.. There are lots of plugins that advertise, with links to their website..

Comment: You have two negatives in your sentence so it doesn't make sense what you are writing and I don't think you understand what I'm asking...

Comment: so will you please explain your problem better, so people here can help you? Your plugin just pulls data from your server, it does not embed link to your website in themes, does it? You better read this thoroughly http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/about/

Comment: I will use php command to pull data from mydomain.com/text.txt and the plugin will update their db with the info it received from the text file...Is this allowed for wp plugin?

Comment: Yes, it is. That is how API consuming plugins work.. Also it would be a better practice to let user decide if they want to do it or not.

Comment: yeah, that's what I wanted to know. Is there some info about the API consuming plugins?

Comment: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=api all these plugins pull OR submit data to some external link..